# Print multiple pages of same report with different data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My .rpt file contains information regarding the salary of many employees. I can print once for each of their salary data, but I would like to generate the data for all employees in the report viewer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make a second report! Keep the current one you're using, but save a new copy of the .RPT and modify it to display the information you want. (So then you'll have `SingleEmployee.rpt` and `AllEmployees.rpt`)

In this case, have it display all valid employees in the report *at the same time* instead of just data for one employee. You might also want to add a group based on the employee's name in order to alphabetize the records. This way you can design the new report to display just the way you want.

---

If that's not an option, and you absolutely have to keep it all in one report, you could set your employee parameter to be optional. If left blank, tell the record selection formula you want every employee to print out. If *not* blank, only print for that specific employee.